# mysql: getting getting tuple of an alias which has maximum column value

Tags: mysql, sql, max, alias

What I want to do is this:

```
select AlbumId from (
    select Album.AlbumId, Sum(Track.UnitPrice) as Total from Album 
    inner join Track on Album.AlbumId = Track.AlbumId
    group by Album.AlbumId
) tpt 
where Total = (select max(Total) from tpt);
```

but am getting:

> Table 'db.tpt' doesn't exist

-which probably makes sense. However, I am new to SQL and don't know why tpt goes out of scope in my where clause. How can I achieve this? I want to get the tuple with the Max total and extract the `AlbumId`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `JOIN` with subqueries.

```
select tpt.AlbumId from (
    select Album.AlbumId, Sum(Track.UnitPrice) as Total from Album 
    inner join Track on Album.AlbumId = Track.AlbumId
    group by Album.AlbumId
) tpt 
JOIN (
    select Sum(Track.UnitPrice) as Total from Album 
    inner join Track on Album.AlbumId = Track.AlbumId
    group by Album.AlbumId
    ORDER BY Total DESC
    LIMIT 1
) maxtpt ON tpt.Total = maxtpt.Total
```

Comment: will this work if multiple albums share the maximum price..(i.e. will it spit out 2 albumId's if two albumId's share the maximum value?)

Comment: No, it won't. I'll revise.